# How to display an array of multiple images?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, image, plugins

I am using this wordpress plugin to upload multiple images. http://wordpress.org/plugins/upload-multiple-image/

It gives me a function that return an array `get_multiple_image($post_id)`. But next I don't know how to display this array?

I want to display all images in this format.

What I should do to get images path in `$img1`, `$img2`, `$img3`, `$img4`.

```
<img src="<?php echo $img1; ?>" alt="">
<img src="<?php echo $img2; ?>" alt="">
<img src="<?php echo $img3; ?>" alt="">
<img src="<?php echo $img4; ?>" alt="">
```

if I do this `print_r(get_multiple_image($post_id));` it return this

```
Array ( [0] => http://localhost/arabian/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/flaconi-bag1.png [1] => http://localhost/arabian/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/hoods-products1.png [2] => http://localhost/arabian/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/product-ring1.png [3] => http://localhost/arabian/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/soud-gloves1.png )
```

Comment: print_r(get_multiple_image($post_id)) and show your output

Comment: If you want to output the img-tags you can use a foreach loop

Comment: what is the array format? paste a sample array

Comment: Thanks rakesh sharma... now I get an array see in question. How can i save this array in $img1, $img2, .......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and easy:

```
// Get images as array
$images = get_multiple_image($post_id);

// Loop over images and echo
foreach($images as $img) {
    echo '<img src="'.$img.'" alt="">';
}
```

Or if you want to set an alternative image text derived from the loop index:

```
// Loop over images and echo
for($i = 0; $i < count($images); $i++) {
    echo '<img src="'.$images[$i].'" alt="Image #'.($i+1).'">';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$images = get_multiple_image($post_id);
foreach($images as $img) {?>
<img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" alt="">
<?php }?>
```

or for path you  can use array index values

```
$img1 = $images[0];
$img2 = $images[1];
```

and so on....

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$AllImages = get_multiple_image($post_id);

foreach($AllImages as $image)
{
  echo "<img src='".$image."' alt=''>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$images=array('http://localhost/arabian/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/flaconi-bag1.png','http://localhost/arabian/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/hoods-products1.png','http://localhost/arabian/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/product-ring1.png','http://localhost/arabian/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/soud-gloves1.png');

print_r($images);
foreach($images as $key){
echo "<img src='".$key."' alt=''>";
}
```

The output will be,

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://localhost/arabian/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/flaconi-bag1.png
    [1] => http://localhost/arabian/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/hoods-products1.png
    [2] => http://localhost/arabian/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/product-ring1.png
    [3] => http://localhost/arabian/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/soud-gloves1.png
) // your array
```

and the result

```
<img src='http://localhost/arabian/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/flaconi-bag1.png' alt=''>
<img src='http://localhost/arabian/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/hoods-products1.png' alt=''>
<img src='http://localhost/arabian/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/product-ring1.png' alt=''>
<img src='http://localhost/arabian/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/soud-gloves1.png' alt=''>
```

[See example](http://codepad.org/yaTLASez)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$MultiImages = get_multiple_image($post_id);

foreach($MultiImages as $img)
{
  echo "<img src='".$img."' alt=''>";
}
```